# How to do conditional formatting with time in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

I am trying to do conditional formatting with time, in one column I have present time i.e. using `=NOW()`, in other columns I have a set of time between 0-24 Hrs. All the columns have time in `HH:MM::SS` format.

When I use conditional formatting on the set of time values such that if present time is between start time and end time, the cells should turn to orange color, if start time and end time was before present time then the cell should be in yellow color, if start time and end time is later than present time the cell should be in green color. Applying conditional formatting works only once but I want the sheet to be dynamic i.e. the cells should change their colors according to real time values.

Please find the following example image

[image: Excel columns]

Comment: What conditional formatting formula have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to format all times between 12 - 13 as blue? Or do you want the format to relate to the NOW() time stamp? Please edit your question and provide a better example. Then post a comment to alert the followers of the question.

Comment: Also a similar question was already asked: https://superuser.com/questions/826773/conditional-formatting-if-one-time-is-greater-than-the-other

Comment: @teylyn format should relate to NOW()

Comment: Please edit your question and add clarification there. If you can't follow these simple instructions, then you won't get much out of this site. Use your reading skills, take the [tour] and follow the advice you see in comments.

Comment: @Olly@Pierre44@teylyn Please find the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer edited, as question clarified:

You could try the following conditional formatting formulae:

Yellow:

```
=AND($F3<NOW()-TODAY(),$H3<NOW()-TODAY())
```

Orange:

```
=AND($F3<NOW()-TODAY(),$H3>NOW()-TODAY())
```

Green:

```
=AND($F3>NOW()-TODAY(),$H3>NOW()-TODAY())
```

Apply each formula to range F3:H6, and format to suit.

[image]

Comment: almost like I wanted it to, can we add minutes too ? i.e. I wanted the cells to be dynamically update colors with time.

Comment: You need to [edit] your original question to make your requirement much clearer, with examples of your exact input / expected output, what you have already tried, and the problem you are having.

Comment: As has the answer

Comment: the formatting is taking different colors when selecting F:H full column range, like the first formula selects all cells except specified cells, second formula fills orange to first row and green is absent even after applying third formula.

Comment: Think carefully about the formula you use, and the cell references in the formula. The formulas in my answer work for the data range in your question (F3:H3) - if you're changing the range that the formatting applies to, then you'll need to change the formulas accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, got the correct formatting after applying formulas in the right way.